# Publishing failed due to Error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: SortExpression.SortExpression

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing

We recently upgraded from Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. We are using VBScript for Templating. While trying to publish items we are getting the following error"

> Error: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: SortExpression.SortExpression
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
>
> Errorcode: 0
>
> User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.KeywordRelatedFilter.set_SortExpression(String)
>       Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.TaxonomyFacade.GetListKeywords(UserContext,String,ListColumnFilter,String,EnumKeywordSortType)
>       Category.GetListKeywords
>       UtilitiesPublish.RenderComponentPresentation
>       ComponentPresentation.Render
>       UtilitiesPublish.RenderPage
>       Page.Render
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Legacy.Rendering.PageRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext context)
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction, TransportPackage transportPackage)
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
>          at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()

The code for retrieving Keywords is as below:

```
Set objGovCat = TDSE.GetObject(emField("EmbeddedFieldURI").Value(1) , 1) 
Set lStrXml = GetNewDomDocument()
lStrXml.loadXML(objGovCat.GetListKeywords(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Publishing is fixed after passing XMLListIDAndTitle in to GetListKeywords method so the updated code is now

```
Set objGovCat = TDSE.GetObject(emField("EmbeddedFieldURI").Value(1) , 1) 
Set lStrXml = GetNewDomDocument()
lStrXml.loadXML(objGovCat.GetListKeywords(XMLListIDAndTitle))
```